# Consistency of Nontrivial Elementary Embedding from $\omega_1$ to itself?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

I was wondering about a way to make really large countable ordinals. It turns out that in certain models of ZFC (for example pointwise definable ones) every ordinal is definable with *no* parameters, which means you can't expect your ordinal to exist in every model of ZFC without having some FOST (language of first-order set theory) equivalent characterization.

Of course, one can simply make an axiom (a scheme with constant a symbol) to create such an ordinal which is not definable within ZFC (unless something with $\omega$-consistency, I don’t know what really). One can then make a scheme with more constant symbols that are all ordinals which cannot be defined from previous ordinals.

A sort of "limit" of this is making an axiom stating the existence of an elementary embedding from $\omega_1$ to itself with a critical point. I believe this could quite easily be proven inconsistent, but I'm not sure how to start.

I call this "The Axiom of Countable Ineffability" or $\text{CI}$ for short. Here's the formal definition of $\text{CI}(Q)$ for a set of formulae $Q$:

1. There is some ordinal $\alpha\in\omega_1$ such that $j(\alpha)\neq\alpha$
2. For every $\alpha\in\omega_1$, $j(\alpha)\in\omega_1$.
3. For every $\varphi\in Q$, an axiom stating that for any $\alpha_0,\alpha_1...\in\omega_1$ with $\varphi^{\omega_1}(\alpha_0,\alpha_1...)$, $\varphi^{\omega_1}(j(\alpha_0),j(\alpha_1)...)$

Of course, because it only quantifies over $\varphi^{\omega_1}$ for FOST $\varphi$, for which there exists a set-sized truth predicate in $V$ (defined on the set of all finite sequences of countable ordinals), **this can be stated as a single FOST axiom (as long as the class $\{\varphi^{\omega_1}:\varphi\in Q\}$).** In fact, this is true for any uncountable ordinal, not just $\omega_1$.

---

**The Questions**

1. What is the consistency of $\text{ZFC}+\text{CI}(\Sigma_n)$?
2. What is the consistency of $\text{ZFC}+\text{CI}$?

Comment: Does your ZFC+CI include instances of replacement (or collection and separation) that involve the new symbol $j$, or only the instances in the original language of ZFC?

Comment: What is FOST and IDK?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek FOST = the language of first-order set theory, IDK = I don't know

Comment: It follows from $0^\sharp$.  I would guess it’s equivalent.

Comment: When you say elementary embedding of $\omega_1$ into itself what language are you talking about? If it's just $\omega_1$ as a linear order then I think there's an explicit ZFC definable non-trivial elementary embedding of it into itself.

Comment: How so @JamesHanson?

Comment: Very little is actually first-order definable in ordinals as pure linear orders. I believe that $\omega^{\omega+1} = \omega^\omega \times \omega$ has $\omega^{\omega}\times \{0,2,3,4,\dots\}$ (i.e. delete the second $\omega^\omega$ block) as an isomorphic proper elementary substructure, which implies that for any ordinal $\alpha \geq \omega^{\omega+1}$ there's an explicit ZFC definable non-trivial elementary embedding of $\alpha$ into itself as a linear order.

Comment: @Zetatopology:  Are you interested in a nontrivial elementary embedding from $\omega_1$ into itself or of an $\omega_1$-model of $ZFC$ into itself?  Please clarify.